# What is the proper way of zipping Flux with Mono?

Tags: java, functional-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

There's a `Mono<A>` and `Flux<B>`, and we need to create a flux of tuples like this:

```
Mono<A> monoA = createMono(); // {a}
Flux<B> fluxB = createFlux(); // {b1, b2, ... b100, ...}

Flux<Tuple<A,B>> zippedTuples = magicZip(monoA, fluxB); // { (a:b1), (a:b2), ... (a:b100), ...}
```

What is the proper (or standard) way to write the `magicZip` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this method:

```
private <T>Flux<Tuple2<T, T>> magicZip(Mono<T> mono, Flux<T> flux) {
    Flux<T> repeatableMono = mono.repeat();
    return flux.zipWith(repeatableMono);
}
```

Example for the String type:

```
    Flux<Tuple2<String, String>> test = magicZip(getMono(), getFlux()).doOnNext(objects -> System.out.println(objects.getT1() + objects.getT2()));
    test.blockLast();
```

Comment: Yes, that's what is required. It would be useful to mention that `mono.repeat()` will execute mono as many times as number of items in flux. In most situations `mono.cache().repeat()` is the most applicable.

Comment: Yes, good point, I thought to add this operator, but l concentrated only on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with zip function is not possible because it produces as many elements as the smallest of two.

The way I think you can achive this is:

```
Flux<A> fluxA = monoA.flux();
Flux<Tuple2<A,B>> zippedTuples =fluxB.flatMap(b -> fluxA.map(a -> Tuples.of(a,b)));
```

Comment: monoA.flux() creates a flux with one item, so zipped Flux will also contain a single tuple, dropping all the others

Comment: Yes, because of this I do not use zipp, this is what I say at the begining. The way to do it is not by using zip but using flatMap and map instead